# In what cases, if any, is there a difference in performance between prefix and postfix increment/decrement operators in C?

Tags: c, post-increment, pre-increment

I understand that this issue in C++ can be a matter of [copying the object and|or overload](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/59880/avoid-postfix-increment-operator). I also understand that optimization comes into play and can make this a non issue in most, if not all cases. My question is whether or not current compilers make this a complete non-issue or there are still some occasions to consider a difference.

Comment: I am explicitly asking about `C` though.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is very simple: If you measure it, and you get a significant difference, then you have a difference in performance. If you don't measure it, there is no difference. At least not to you, because you couldn't be bothered about measuring.

That applies to all speed related questions, actually.